# Why won't `system` create and return a variable?

Tags: bash, r

In R, When I run

```
system("FOO='test123'")
```

I would expect

```
system("echo $FOO")
```

to return

```
test123
```

in the same way that

```
system("echo $USER")
```

returns my username

But it returns nothing. Why is this?

---

Why would anyone want to do this? I was trying to simulate the use of `env FOO='test1234 R -vanilla < script.R` while writing `script.R`, which in turn calls `system("echo $FOO`)`

Comment: Use `Sys.setenv` if you want to set environment variables that will persist for your R session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know R, but in other languages `system()` (at least on Unix-like systems) creates a new shell (/bin/sh) process to execute the command.  Your `FOO='test123'` sets the value of `$FOO`, but only within that process.  Your `system("echo $FOO")` executes in a new process in which `$FOO` hasn't been set.

If R has a way to set environment variables internally (`setenv`, perhaps?), you should use that instead.

**EDIT**: As @Joshua says in a comment, it's `Sys.setenv`.

Comment: Oh, and `FOO='test123'` doesn't create an environment variable, it just creates a shell variable (not inherited by subprocesses) unless you `export` it.

Answer (score 6):

Each system call will fire up a NEW shell, with its own environment. Variables set in one shell will not carry over to subsequent shells - they'll each be completely independent of each other.